# NFC Read Tag in iOS

Tags: ios, nfc

On tap button, I begin session for reading a tag, after that, a popup opens with a heading "Ready to Scan". Can I hide this popup by own? After reading the tag hide popup from the screen. Is there any functionality for this? In my project. I need to hide this:
[image: popup]

Comment: No, it is displayed by iOS and you can't hide it or change its appearance

Comment: Paulw11 Is there any apple site link (authenticate link) from where I can get this information?

Comment: I am not aware of any specific documentation that says what you *can't do*, but the Core NFC document says what you *can do* and nowhere does it say you can suppress the dialog. Dialogs of that form are presented by the operating system and cannot be suppressed.  It is just like the TouchID/FaceID dialog. It is presented because your app does not have access to the NFC hardware. Core NFC calls out to a privileged process to complete the read.  This process displays the dialog while it is in control and gives the user an opportunity to cancel.

Comment: Any update on this? Is it still impossible today?

Answer (score 0):

Apple published some example project for NFC here which might be useful for you, unfortenately it's in Swift:

https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/CoreNFC-Tag-Reading.zip

However, taking a look at the API specification: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc?language=objc, Apple did not expose any API's to allow you to hide the alert UI. It's built in iOS.

> Can I hide this popup by own?

So, sorry, I am affraid you cannot.

Comment: Any update on this? Is it still impossible today?

Comment: Yeah, still impossible.